# Is there a generic way to do comparison both numeric and string in Perl?

Tags: string, perl, numeric

As everyone knows, the numeric's comparison uses different operators to string's. 
So Is there a generic way to do comparison both numeric and string in Perl ? 
Should I always check the value is numeric or string before doing the comparison?
I am a freshman in Perl. Please help if you have some idea.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you think the answer should be if you compare a string against a number? Why don't you know what type your input data will contain?

Comment: can you give an example when you run into such a situation?

Comment: In fact, the user will config which part of a text he needs, and compare a value he specified. So the user knows what type of the data is. Sometimes the data is numeric, and sometimes is string. Yes, I can do the type-check before comparison. But the code is not generic. Because the comparison logic is same. So I think maybe there is a generic way to do it in Perl. Or maybe there isn't. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to ways already mentioned, when using perl > 5.10.1, [smart matching](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) can be used. Specifically look at lines 29 .. 32 in the referenced table. If one operand look like a number, numeric comparison is used, otherwise fallback to string.

Comment: According to the environment, I only can use Perl 5.8.8.

Answer (score 1):

Well, usually you know what kind of data a particular variable holds at a particular point in time.  Can you explain more what case you are thinking of where you wouldn't?

There are modules tailored to things like complex version numbers that may have multiple string/numeric parts.  [Sort::Naturally](http://p3rl.org/Sort%3a%3aNaturally) is one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use numeric comparison when you want to compare numbers and string comparison when you want to compare strings. That's really all there is to it. You're probably overthinking it.

If you *really* need to test for both string and numeric equality, just test for both:

```
if ( ( $foo eq $bar ) && ( $foo == $bar ) )
```

Comment: This seems like it would be overkill, I can't think of a case, short of `overload` or `tie`, that would return true for `eq` and false for `==`.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, use `eq`. It works for numbers as well. You only need numeric operations when you want to count something.

Perl will convert numbers to strings and vice-versa when needed, however, not all strings can be represented by numbers, so you'll get a warning and a zero value (while we are at it: **always** `use strict;` and `use warnings;` ).